# Disable Double click event in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My click event is working and i wanted to disable double click. But it is not working

Click Event:

```
  $(document).on("click", ".firstlevel, .secondlevel, .thirdlevel", function () {   
      if ($(this).parent().siblings(".k-icon") !== undefined) {
          $(".preloader").fadeOut();
          $(this).parent().siblings(".k-icon").click();         
      }
  });

  $(document).on("dblclick", ".firstlevel, .secondlevel, .thirdlevel", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropogation();
    });
```

Comment: You have typo: *e.stopProp`o`gation()*

Comment: Why exactly do you want "disable" double click? Maybe there's another way to do what you want achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use **.off()** method of jquery to remove  event handlers associated with given selectors?

http://api.jquery.com/off/

```
$(document).off("dblclick", ".firstlevel, .secondlevel, .thirdlevel")
```

Comment: jQuery's one() will fire the attached event handler once for each element bound, and then remove the event handler.

If for some reason that doesn't fulfill the requirements, one could also disable the button entirely after it has been clicked.